# Include node_module into Ember component

Tags: javascript, ember.js, wavesurfer.js

I am trying to add wavesurfer to my application. I did exactly according to the instructions. at: https://www.npmjs.com/package/wavesurfer.js

After I did bower install I had wavesurfer.js folder inside my node_modules

> import WaveSurfer from 'wavesurfer.js';

Theoretically WaveSurfer class should be available on my component. But after I include above code I have this error

```
Uncaught Error: Could not find module wavesurfer.js
at requireModule (loader.js:58)
at reify (loader.js:41)
at requireModule (loader.js:69)
at Class._extractDefaultExport (ember-resolver.js:390)
at Class.resolveOther (ember-resolver.js:122)
at Class.superWrapper [as resolveOther] (ember.debug.js:17407)
at Class.resolve (ember.debug.js:4597)
at Registry.resolve [as resolver] (ember.debug.js:4437)
at resolve (ember.debug.js:2109)
at Registry.resolve (ember.debug.js:1715)
```

I killed almost a week on this.

How can I make that class available for my component

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, open your `ember-cli-build.js` and import the library as follows:

```
  // if you used npm then:
  app.import('node_modules/<path-to-wavesurfer.js>');

  // if you used bower then:
  app.import('bower_components/<path-to-wavesurfer.js>');
```

depending on which package manager you used to install the dependency.
I did a quick search and found this shim: https://github.com/chrism/ember-cli-wavesurfer-js-shim, which probably includes the lib into the build. However, doesn't seem to be working with up-to-date Ember.

Comment: I do not know where should be ember-cli-build.js
In whole project I have several ember-cli-build.js files in different node_modules

Comment: in the parent directory. The upper directory of your ember app, the one with app/, tests/, package.json etc.

Comment: I do not have ember-cli-build.js file in my project. However, I created that file and added app.import('bower_components/<path-to-wavesurfer.js>');
The same result: Could not find result wavesurfer.js

Comment: If you are not building your Ember project with CLI, just downloading npm module won't help you. You need to include the downloaded JS library.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not building your Ember app via [ember-cli](https://ember-cli.com/), you could try adding the library into your `index.html` file

`<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/wavesurfer.js/1.4.0/wavesurfer.min.js"></script>`

and assign it a container `<div id="waveform"></div>` as explained at [wavesurfer-js.org](https://wavesurfer-js.org/)

Comment: Ho it does not work. I add these cdn into my index.html it appears on header. But when I use class Wavesurfer it says me undefined Wavesurfer